# Why does Xcode auto-fix create two methods with the same name `func tableView`?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am new to swift programming language. I've seen that in creating table in Swift, you have to implement two methods in ViewController class that extends `UITableViewDelegate`, `UITableViewDataSource`. What I don't understand is, why does Xcode's auto-fix create two methods with the same name `func tableView` in this class?

Is this not going to create method overloading or cause bug down the road?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    let dataArray = ["firt", "second", "third", "four", "five", "six"]

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let videoCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "video title", for: indexPath)

        return videoCell
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Even though they have the same function name `tableView`

They are very different functions. 
They both conform to the UITableView delegate and based on its protocol method will affect different functionalities of the tableView.

```
didSelectRowAt
```

is not the same as

```
cellForRowAt
```

- Did Select row at is only triggered when you obviously select a cell
- Cell for row at is considered the 'main' tableView function, as this function populates your tableView data cells.

--EDIT
Based on Duncan C comment below.

" the name of your example function is not tableView, The name of of the function is tableView(_:cellForRowAt:) (The parameters are actually part of the function's name, or rather it's function "signature.") "

This is an excellent way to describe the answer.

Edit 2----

Furthermore,
This is very common among programming in swift. The most direct example would be `collectionView`. It uses almost the identical naming convention.

```
cellForRowAt
```

and

```
didSelectRowAt
```

There are many other delegate methods that you will encounter with the same situation as you describe in your question.

Comment: To add to this. In Object Oriented Programming there is the concept of polymorphism. The idea is that you can use the same method and it will do different things dependent on external factors. This is a perfect example of that showing two apparent `tableView` methods but their parameters are different. This will cause the compiler to find the method associated with the given parameters, aka overloading. Overloading IS NOT what you're thinking it is. It is polymorphism. You will see this tons and tons once you get deeper into programming.

Comment: Adding to what Julian and xTwistedDx, the name of your example function is not `tableView`, The name of of the function is `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` (The parameters are actually part of the function's name, or rather it's function "signature.")

Comment: @DuncanC that is a better way of describing the answer. I will update answer to include that

Answer (score 2):

They are actually different methods. Each one overrides some properties of your TableView.
Just pay attention to the parameters of each function.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

This method creates and configures an appropriate cell for the given index path.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

Here you decide what happens when cell rows are clicked (go to another view, display some content, etc)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
```

Returns the number of rows each section of your TableView should have.

And so on. There are many others methods that you can use for different  reasons. To see which methods you can override, type `tableView` on your Xcode and see the autocomplete options.

Answer (score 0):

That is called method overloading. Swift designers chose to follow this way of writing functions to make it easier for the programmers to find all related tableView functions. That tableView has many more functions like:

a one that has `heightForRowAt` and `willDisplayCell` in its parameters. Swift utilizes heavily a pattern called **Delegate Pattern**, the framework calls these tableView functions when you assign your ViewController as a delegate.

Comment: If you're using a TableViewController then you won't be assigning a delegate, it will be baked right in.